# Excel VBA: Passing a variable sized two dimensional array to user selected range

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks in advance for your time!

So, my code is designed to allow a user to select a range that contains data, which is passed into an array.  I use a do while loop to manipulate the data and pass it into a new array, the dimensions of which are a function of the size of the first one.

What I'd like to do is allow the user to select a cell to serve as the top left of the destination range for this new array, much like one can identify the starting point for an ANOVA table and such.

I've been trying to use an Application.Inbox for the user to select the cell, but it's just not working.

Here's generally what I've got:

```
'Allocate Array
arrayCustNum = Application.InputBox("Select Customer Number Range", "Customer Range", Type:=8)
arrayData = Application.InputBox("Select Data Range (no headers or cust numbers)", "Data Range", Type:=8)
arrayDataHeader = Application.InputBox("Select Data Header Range", "Data Header Range", Type:=8)    

'Allocate Destination Array
ReDim arrayDest(UBound(arrayData, 1) * UBound(arrayData, 2) + 2, UBound(arrayData, 2))
```

The loop happens, and then we move to output:

```
Set rngPos = Range(Application.InputBox("Event Table will be size (" & UBound(arrayDest, 1) & _
", " & UBound(arrayDest, 2) & "). Choose the top left cell of desired location.", _
"Output Location", Type:=64))

rngPos.Resize(UBound(arrayDest, 1), UBound(arrayDest, 2)).Value = arrayDest
```

An error is thrown that simply says "400."

Appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `64` is for `array`. Also pass the address as parameter to the `Range` function to return a range.

```
Set rngPos = Range(Application.InputBox("Event Table will be size (" & UBound(arrayDest, 1) & _
", " & UBound(arrayDest, 2) & "). Choose the top left cell of desired location.", _
"Output Location", Type:=8).Address)
```

Comment: `Application.InputBox( ... , Type:=8)` returns a range reference.  Imbedding that into `Set rngPos = Range( InputBox( ... , Type:=8).Address)` is pointless, just use `Set rngPos = InputBox( ... , Type:=8)`